# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' em chamada de AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mvc, controller

Olá

Estou com um erro numa chamada de AJAX no meu JavaScript. Por alguma razão, ele não chega na função na minha Controller e dá o seguinte erro: **SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'**.

Essa função é chamada assim que eu clico num botão de uma Modal. Ela serve para criar os dados de um DataTable já criado.

```
function EWBuild() {
  $.ajax({
      url: urlCreateBH,
      data: { year: $('#findYearBH').val(), inputType: 1, month: $('#monthEW').val() },
      dataType: "script",
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (result) {
          CreateTableEW(result);
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: `dataType: 'script'` espera um código Javascript. Tem algum retorno errado n o seu `urlCreateBH`. Provavelmente, está retornando 404. Você precisa conferir isso na aba newtwork do chrome.

Comment: Tente adicionar dentro do seu ajax uma `error: function(status, error, e){
    console.log(error);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(e);
}` e cheque o console do seu navegador.

Comment: quais são os valores de `$('#monthEW').val() ` e `$('#monthEW').val()`? Se não forem numericos eles precisam estar entre aspas.

Comment: Se você quer passar dados no post, mude o `dataType` para `json` e edite o objeto como se fosse um objeto json.